# Does tensorflow.keras fit_generator function use GPU by default?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu

I'm trying to implement a custom DataGenerator class which reads data from disk. If I use fit_generator function, will the GPU be used by default?

Comment: No. If you would like a particular operation to run on a device of your choice instead of what's automatically selected for you, you can use with `tf.device` to create a device context, and all the operations within that context will run on the same designated device. For more information you can refer [Use a GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu). Thanks!

Comment: Is this for tensorflow version 2.x?